# Multiple MySQL columns linking to same reference table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a front-end developer that needs a quick pointer for data that I am trying to get from a MySQL database.

There is a table 'events' which includes multiple columns, including 'host_country' and 'visiting_country' (events.host_country & events.visiting country). Both of these columns contain numbers to refer to various countries, the values of which are stored in a 'countries' table.

The 'countries' table has two columns: 'countries.id' and 'countries.name'. I need to display the name of both the visiting and host countries.

I can get one of the 'event' columns to work with a join, but it doesn't seem feasible to use two joins on the same 'countries' table.

Is there any way to use the 'countries' table to get the names for both events.visiting_country and events.host_country?

Thank you!
Matt

Comment: you need to join with countries table twice to get host and visiting country name, there is no other way.

Answer (score 2):

```
select e.*, c1.name, c2.name
  from event e
    inner join countries c1
      on c1.id = e.host_country
    inner join countries c2
      on c2.id = e.visiting_country;
```

join the countries table twice. here's a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b785/1